# Apollo Client Cache Diagnostic Tooling and Techniques

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client, hasura

What are some tools or techniques that would allow me to achieve the following with with Apollo GraphQL Client:

1. Easily identify which queries were returned from cache vs triggered
   a network request
2. Easily diagnose *why* a specific request did not get a Cache hit

I have the Apollo Chrome Dev Tools installed, which are useful, but (as far as I can tell) don't help much with the above.